# Randomly generated Terrain in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, canvas

I am creating a game similar to Lunar Lander and am attempting to make a simple randomly generated terrain each time the game loads. I am currently generating random points and drawing a curve through these points and the two bottom corners of the canvas.
However for some reason the peak of the curve is being mirrored to the top of the canvas as well as the bottom.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim xpoint1 As Single
Dim ypoint1 As Single
Dim xpoint2 As Single
Dim ypoint2 As Single
Dim xpoint3 As Single
Dim ypoint3 As Single
Dim xpoint4 As Single
Dim ypoint4 As Single
Dim isTerrainDrawn As Integer = 0



Private Sub generateRandomTerrain()

    Dim terrainBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Gray)
    Dim terrainDraw As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

    Dim rand As New Random


    'Generate Different Points for Terrain
    xpoint1 = 40 * rand.Next(0, 10)
    ypoint1 = 40 * rand.Next(0, 10)

    xpoint2 = 40 * rand.Next(10, 20)
    ypoint2 = 40 * rand.Next(10, 20)

    xpoint3 = 40 * rand.Next(20, 30)
    ypoint3 = 40 * rand.Next(20, 30)

    xpoint4 = 40 * rand.Next(0, 10)
    ypoint4 = 40 * rand.Next(0, 10)



    'Generate Points to Draw
    Dim terrain() As Point = {New Point(0, Me.Size.Height), New Point(0, Me.Size.Height - 100), New Point((Me.Size.Width * 0.2) + Me.xpoint1, Me.Size.Height - Me.ypoint1 - 100), New Point((Me.Size.Width * 0.45) + Me.xpoint2, Me.Size.Height - Me.ypoint2 - 100), New Point((Me.Size.Width * 0.75) - Me.xpoint3, Me.Size.Height - 100 - Me.ypoint3), New Point((Me.Size.Width * 0.8) + (Me.Size.Width * 0.05) - Me.xpoint4, Me.Size.Height - Me.ypoint4 - 100), New Point(Me.Size.Width, Me.Size.Height - 100), New Point(Me.Size.Width, Me.Size.Height)}

    'Is Terrain Drawn-Clear
    If Me.isTerrainDrawn = 1 Then
        terrainDraw.Clear(Color.Transparent)
        Me.isTerrainDrawn = 0
    End If

    'Draw Terrain Aspects
    terrainDraw.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    terrainDraw.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    terrainDraw.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver

    'Draw Terrain
    terrainDraw.FillClosedCurve(terrainBrush, terrain)

    'Set Terrain to Drawn
    Me.isTerrainDrawn = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    generateRandomTerrain()
End Sub


End Class
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by mirrored ? Can you show a picture ?

Comment: I don't have any idea about the expected result, you got what you generated. But I can see some problems in the code. ***1)*** Instead of using `CreateGragics`, you should pass `e.Graphics` from `Paint` event and use it. Change the method signature to `Private Sub generateRandomTerrain(terrainDraw As Graphics)` and call it `generateRandomTerrain(e.Graphics)`. ***2)*** Don't clear the graphics using `Transparent` color, clear it using a real color. ***3)*** You are regenerating the shape in paint event, it seems you should create the shape once but put drawing logic in paint event handler.

Comment: Few tips on the graphics: 1) Make sure any assumptions on the point of origin (0,0) are correct. If using a form as drawing surface I believe it was in the upper left corner of the displayed area. 2) When calculating the points to draw need to make some bounding checks. For example if subtracting out the ypoint2 from the height maybe it results in a negative number. Giving a curve that goes outside of your form and get clipped. 3) To debug it try instead of drawning a filled curve draw a series of line with each segment a different color.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Since posting this i have fixed the issue and it now draws how i would like it to. Thanks for the advice. However i now have a different issue. I am using e.graphics to draw a bit map image on the screen and to move it using rotate and translate. To accomplish this i am also using me.refresh, the only problem is that it then generates another random curve every time it refreshes. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @RyanRoos Silly me. Forgot that the TOP left corner was 0,0. I wrote that code think it was the BOTTOM left corner. Thanks :)

Comment: @AdamParker Generate your random curve just once for example in startup of your form, and store it in a `GraphicsPath` or a `Point()` array.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you so much for all the help. It is now working exactly how i would like it to,